# Does Pandas use Numpy as a random number generator?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, random-seed

I want to get reproducible samples of data. A quick experiment suggests, that [`numpy.random.seed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) does influence [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), but it is not documented.

Does anybody know

### What I tried

I ran the following a couple of times and always got the same results back

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 1),
                   (1, 2, 2),
                   (1, 2, 3),
                   (4, 1, 612),
                   (4, 1, 612),
                   (4, 1, 1),
                   (3, 2, 1),
                   ],
                  columns=['groupid', 'a', 'b'],
                  index=['India', 'France', 'England', 'Germany', 'UK', 'USA',
                         'Indonesia'])
np.random.seed(0)
print(df.sample(n=1))
print(df.sample(n=1))
print(df.sample(n=1))
print(df.sample(n=1))
print(df.sample(n=1))
```

Which gives:

- Indonesia
- France
- Indonesia
- USA
- England

Comment: See the RandomState documentation for numpy. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas use `_random_state` function for return `np.random.RandomState` [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4fce7846be56e12999fe8758abb2ea2f2794259d/pandas/core/common.py#L626):

```
def _random_state(state=None):
    """
    Helper function for processing random_state arguments.
    Parameters
    ----------
    state : int, np.random.RandomState, None.
        If receives an int, passes to np.random.RandomState() as seed.
        If receives an np.random.RandomState object, just returns object.
        If receives `None`, returns np.random.
        If receives anything else, raises an informative ValueError.
        Default None.
    Returns
    -------
    np.random.RandomState
    """

    if types.is_integer(state):
        return np.random.RandomState(state)
    elif isinstance(state, np.random.RandomState):
        return state
    elif state is None:
        return np.random
    else:
        raise ValueError("random_state must be an integer, a numpy "
                         "RandomState, or None")
```

and in [sample](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.21.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L3374) is called this function:

```
    # Process random_state argument
    rs = com._random_state(random_state)
```